# API Jar for Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

We use an "enterprise" app which deploys Hazelcast.  Every minor version upgrade is a pain, because the vendor has to become involved.

Any chance Hazelcast.org could deploy a hazelcast-api.jar on which the legacy app could depend at compile-time, leaving us free to deploy the compatible version of our choice for runtime use?

Thanks, Robin.

Answer (score 0):

Robin,

Currently it's not possible we at Hazelcast have this requirement in mind for future hazelcast versions (maybe in Hazelcast 4).

Let me know if you have an questions.